# Excel Chart: Title & Axis Tiles based on named range

Tags: excel, charts, named-ranges

I thought this should work, but at times Excel has a tendency to make simple things complicated (or impossible).

I'm setting up a bunch of graphs. Because I anticipate I will have to translate labels at some point, I want to use named ranges for all my labels (then'll offset it for translation). There's VBA involved for other stuff already, so I kinda like to use name manager as much as possible. I think it makes things easier to maintain as well.

The problem arises when I try to set the Axis Titles, and the chart Title, as a reference to a cell that is a named range. I know I can set the reference to a CELL, by doing so entering in the formula bar while having the title selected something like:

```
=worksheetname!$A$1
```

However, let's say that my that cell is named graphlabel_waterpointY. I would like to do something like:

```
=graphlabel_waterpointY
```

Which fails. Upon diggin a bit, I found that I need to put the workbook's name before I can use the named range as such, like so:

```
=WORKBOOKNAME.XLSM!graphlabel_waterpointY
```

That works, however, I don't want the user to rename the workbook and later find that all the graphs titles show !VALUE instead of proper titles. Therefore I want some sort of flexible reference for the name of the workbook as well. I don't want to use:

```
=CELL("filename",A1)
```

& isolate the string there, because if the user has another workbook open that can fail as well. So I thought "well, since I'm already using VBA, I'll just set the workbook name in a cell upon workbook opening & have my formula for the titles reference it".

However, that fails as well. Even something like:

```
=META!$A$1!graphlabel_waterpointY
```

(assuming META!$A$1 contains the workbookname) will fail as well.

It seems dumb to me that I would have to hard-code the values. I'm aiming to have something translatable later on. Of course one can just do different version, but then it sucks to have to maintain 2 workbooks. Or I could settle for hard-coding the workbook names & have it said they can't change it. But that sucks as well.

==================

My solution as this point is the first mentioned, e.g. even if the cell has a named range, refer to it by its A1-style reference. Works but then I lose flexibility in the layout..... Maybe I'm being picky....

Comment: `Range().Name.Name` will return the name of the range of cells as a string.

Comment: dumb question: `=INDIRECT(graphlabel_waterpointY)` doesn't work ether?

Comment: No, it does not: "Incorrect function" is what you get. Seems like charts labels don't evaluate all excel functions...

Scott - sorry I might be slow tonight but I can't seem to use that (even NOT within a chart label, e.g. in a cell)